# TypeScript. TSLint does not wok in Types

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

So I cannot understand how to make standardisation and activate semi rule checking option in `tslint.json`. Because for now it does not checks and not produces any error for `Types` in TypeScript. Also in `Interfaces` it wokrs normally and throw an error when I use something different that `;`, so how can I make it for `Types` too?...

```
export type IProps = {
    active?: boolean, // no error
    title?: string; // no error
    text?: string // no error
}
```

tslint.json:

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint-config-airbnb",
    "tslint-eslint-rules",
    "tslint-react"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rulesDirectory": [],
  "rules": {
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "whitespace": [
      false,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: whats in your tslint.json

Comment: @wgcrouch here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`type-literal-delimiter` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/type-literal-delimiter/).  Just change it from `false` to `true` in your `tslint.json`.